# How was the U.S. divided regarding the French Revolution around 1789?

Tags: united-states, french-revolution

How was America divided regarding the French Revolution during the early going (1789-1791, when the French hero of the American War of Independence, Lafayette, was one of its leaders)? What side of the French Revolution would have the U.S. fought for had that decision been based upon a national vote?

Comment: The war of 1812 is a clue..  As is the election if 1800. As was Jefferson's permission for France to recruit and train a battalion on U S soil.

Comment: Just ***which*** Revolutionary France are you referring to? National policies varied greatly as France stumbled through, in short order, the National Constituent Assembly (1789-91), The Legislative Assembly (1791-92), the National Convention (1792-95), the Directorate (1795-1799), The Consulate (1799-1804) or the Empire (1804-1814, 1815).

Comment: Also note that the question is on the boundary of scope - we discourage hypotheticals.  Given that this has already generated multiple answers, I recommend we leave this open, but discourage future hypotheticals.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I wasn't sure about that. Thanks for letting me know. I think I'll rewrite it to ask more about how Americans were split up regarding the French Revolution. thanks

Comment: In my opinion, that is a far more interesting question.  Different enough that you may wish to ask it as a new question - there are some good answers here).

Comment: @TomAu Does adding 1789 help?

Comment: This is just a sketch, but there was an early, "pure" phase from 1789-92, the reign of Terror from 1792-95, the "Directory," from 1795-98, and later the Napoleonic phase. I may have a few dates mixed up, but you see why the question is confusing. Put another way, the answer to your question of which side would which Americans have taken depends on the subperiod. American nearly went to war with France around 1797, then was a quasi-ally in 1812. Even Jefferson was of two minds. Basically pro-French, he said, "we will have to marry ourselves to the British fleet and nation" without Louisiana.

Comment: Jefferson expressed doubts? I thought he was pretty hard core - anything that was willing to kill British was OK with him, and nothing the French did was ever wrong.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: It's here (longest paragraph). http://www.let.rug.nl/usa/presidents/thomas-jefferson/letters-of-thomas-jefferson/jefl146.php Basically, the same person thought opposite things about the "French Revolution" on different days. Which is why I VTC.

Comment: @TomAu Okay, I removed mention of Washington and the washington tag. No answers mentioned Washington anyways.

Comment: I narrowed this question (and retracted my close vote).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

America supported the crown of France, the Bourbons, who had provided them huge amounts of money and other support during the American Revolution. When the French revolutionaries deposed and executed the King of France, the United States refused paying any debts to France on the grounds that the money had been lent by the King and only would we repay the King. Because of this the French Republicans attacked the United States on the high seas, causing a brief war, called the [Quasi War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-War).

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Madison was president in 1812, not Jefferson.

Comment: Mea Culpa - you are entirely correct.  I have deleted my error in shame.

Answer (score 3):

After and during the French Revolution, people in America were split among the decisions, especially along the party lines. One party supported it, mainly the Democratic-Republicans, and one party was against the revolution, the Federalists, so it would depend on who had more power in the congress on how they would intervene. (Source: Prentice Hall, United States History, history textbook)

Comment: The Federalists were pro-British; the Democratic-Republicans were pro-French.   In general the North was pro-British and the South pro-French.  This was a major issue during the election of 1800; Jefferson backed the French while Adams backed the UK.  Between Adam's grotesque mismanagement of his political capital (he effectively ended the Federalist party), British impressment and early victories by New England sailors against the British fleet, Jefferson managed a majority that backed France.